# Why do we need both, unset and session destroy when we are doing LOGOUT.php?

Tags: php, session, logout, unset

```
?php session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["user_name"]))
if($_GET["destroy"]=="yes")
{
session_destroy();
unset($_SESSION["user_name"]);

}

if(!isset($_SESSION["user_name"]) &&
$_GET["user"]!="")
$_SESSION["user_name"] = $_GET["user"];

?>
```

i was wondering, why would we need both unset and session_destroy()? i tested by removed either one of them,and the result was still the same. the user still logged out. please someone explain to me, thank so much.

Comment: Who says that you would need both in the first place? Please provide some reference otherwise it is not clear what you are actually concerned about.

Comment: Are session_unset() and unset($_SESSION['user']) the same?

Comment: here the link from http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php  it says, In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset.

Comment: in this case, session ID is user_name?

Comment: @HamDlink: No, the session id is not a session variable, the session id ís a property of the actual session. session has: 1.) a name http://php.net/session_name, 2.) an id http://php.net/session_id and 3.) all the session variables http://php.net/$_SESSION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session_unset() delete only a variables from session - session still exist-Only data are truncated.But session_unset() is an outdated PHP function. We can set the session to an empty array instead.

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

session_destroy() will delete whole session.
It's not always necessary to do both.But it is advisable to do both just to ensure extra security.

Comment: session_unset() is an outdated PHP function. it was originally used together with session_register() which you do not use any longer (or if you use it, it's your fault),

Comment: @shrikanth, your answer does make sense because either one will log user out, but for extra security, that why we use both.

Comment: You have a wrong understanding of security here. `session_unset()` was designed for global variables registered as session variables back in PHP 4. As the manual page says, there is no need to use it any longer when you use `$_SESSION`. Also there is no security implication with having data in `$_SESSION` *after* `session_destroy()`, the anser gives no reasoning as well why this actually is *adviseable*. It's only some sentences typed in with no further meaning.

Comment: And don't accept this as an answer, you only did misunderstood what the session id is in your question as we found out. no need to accept a wrong answer. Don't turn a little mistake into another mistake for no reason.

Comment: @hakre yes you are right session_unset() is outdated,we can set the **session** equal to an **empty array** instead.But he mentioned session_unset() in the question so I just explained what it does.

Comment: I mean using both, we just get rid of  the session data in every possible way

Comment: @Shrikanth: session_unset is ***not*** mentioned in the question. And introducing superfluous code is the opposite of every *possible* way. As criticized, you give no reason.

Comment: what i understand is unset($_SESSION["user_name"]) mean delete variable user name. and session_destroy() mean delete all session.
so if i use only session_destroy(), the variable user_name is still there. but if i use on unset($_SESSION["user_name"]), the session still there.

Comment: @HamDlink: yes, exactly. After you've destroyed the session, there is no reason to further manipulate `$_SESSION`.

Comment: @Shrikanth: You miss to share what the *extra* in *extra security* actually is. Please write that as well in your answer while you edit it (and the other linked question in the comments under the question is equally outdated, no need to copy over wrong information from there even it got some upvotes).

Comment: @hakre, if we use both, it will kill the session and the variable.
by killing both, mean extra security.

Comment: @Ham Dlink: You do not need to use both (which was what you *somehow* asked in your question). So don't get fooled thinking writing more code would actually do better or more. The opposite is the case. Writing less code is doing better.

Comment: @hakre, i didn't understand why we need both, but after Shrikanth said about extra security, it does make sense to me. if you destroy only session, the variable is still there.

Comment: @HamDlink By extra security I mean we use both to ensure the session data is destroyed(In case If one fails).If I was wrong please correct it, because I am also a beginner and I just shared what I learned from others

Comment: @Shrikanth: ah that kind of extra securty. well then I actually suggest you to call session_destroy three times in a row so that you know - just for safety - it could have failed two times. :P

Comment: @shrikanth,@hakre, To me extra security means destroy both sesssion and variable.

Comment: @HamDlink: Only Shrikanth wrote about extra secury, it must not mean that this did actually something good.

Comment: @Ham Dlin: Which kind of *extra security* is added when you "destroy" the variable if I may ask you?

Comment: @HamDlink,@harke I learnt php from video tutorial series by Kevin Skoglund. He explained it is a good practice to get rid of session data using both ways together.It destroys both session and variable.

Comment: sorry,i can't answer your question. but i know when i do a log out, i will want to destroy both variable and session. like you said one will be fine. it is just my personal preference to make sure no variable float around after i logged out.

Comment: @shrikanth, i think, you are right.

Comment: @Ham Dlink: You know that in PHP after you script finished no variables float around any longer? And that what is in `$_SESSION` after `session_destroy()` has no meaning at all? Even if you `session_start()` again it would be reset? If those variables still float around and have side effects in your script, then you actually are fixing at the very wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

`unset()` deletes a variable not a session.

`session_destory()` destroys the session.

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current
>   session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with
>   the session, or unset the session cookie.

However, I would suggest that you do a:

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

... instead of `unset();`

Comment: Why would you suggest that?

Comment: its better.  it deletes all values in the session array.  instead of deleting them all one by one.

Comment: well, the OP only used unset in error. there was no reason to use it in the first place, therefore there is no reason to do what you suggest as well.